# How do I run my servelt without a context path (Jetty)

Tags: java, servlets

My Servlet mapping looks like:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So my Servlet responds to requests such as `http://bla.com/myservlet/bla/bla/bla`

How can I make it respond to `http://bla.com/bla/bla/bla` and get rid of the `myservlet` portion of the path.

Further I want to strip the hello world servlet the the default welcome files that come with Jetty.

Thanks.

Note:

1. I know how to do this using `mod_rewrite` / **Apache** -- I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Jetty installation. There are two ways to do it

1. you can rename your war file as `root.war`, makes it's context root as `/`
2. create context.xml for your webapp

   ```xml
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
   <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
   <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
   <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
   <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
   <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/blawh.war</Set>
   ```

   context.xml lives under `$JETTY_HOME/contexts`. As you can see this directory already has context.xml for test.war. You can get decent idea of how your webapp's context.xml should look like by seeing the test.xml.
   Once you are done with creating your own, go ahead and delete `contexts/test.xml`, `contexts/test.d` and `webapps/test.war`. (just to clean test stuffs). This answers your second question too.

If you are using maven, just do this:

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <webAppConfig>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
              </webAppConfig>
              <!-- snip -->
```

refer: [Jetty/Howto/Deploy Web Applications](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications#Deploying_Contexts)

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple url patterns to map to same servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/bla</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/bla/bla</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: the OP actually wants to get rid of `myservlet` part of the URL. The context-root for the application. Your solution does not seem to alter context root. And `bla` does not needed to be taken literally here, imo. I guess he just wanted to match `*`.